Fantasy romance manhua, male character with long blue hair and a special power, female character is a secret agent
So all I can remember is the female lead rescues the male lead from drowning on the first chapters and also there's this casino scene where the female lead was sitting on the male lead's lap to trick him because I think he was her target. There was also this scene when they were hugging in the yacht under one blanket. Also, I think the girl is a secret agent and she's a badass. I forgot the plot but I remember being so hooked to it. I think the female lead has orange/red hair? and the male lead has long blue hair. It's a manhua and I remember reading it on webcomics but idk why it's not there anymore I also forgot the title.
Ps. I think the male lead has a power that makes him special.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are there any science fiction elements in this story?  Works must be on-topic to ask about here.

Hi, yes. I don't know if I'm right but I think the male lead has some power or something that makes him special. It's a fantasy novel as well so I thought some manhua readers here might know.

Can you expand on how it's a fantasy novel? If there's a magic system, elves, poltergeists, demons, etc, that will help us narrow down the answer.

Like I said, I don't remember much because I've read it years ago and I have no idea why I can't find it anywhere on the internet and on the app I read it.  I just remember a few scenes and how the characters look like. No, I don't think there are elves and demons such. Maybe time travelling & transmigration? since manhuas are usually written with that plot.

Did the story take place in a modern setting?

I can sympathize with trying to find a particular work with very vague details, but so far, it feels like the only SF&F tie is "there might have been some fantasy elements that I can't remember and a lot of webtoons are SF&F."

yes, modern setting.

Oh well, It sucks I don't remember much about it so I can't really tell how particularly it was SF&F. But I'm trying my best to remember some details about it. I only asked here because I saw people asking about manhuas and hoped someone knows about it. I'm starting to believe the artist deleted it because I've been searching for hours now and there's not a single thing about it.

I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about science fiction or fantasy.

I'm deleting it. Thanks again!

I flagged my question because it seems I can't delete it on my own. Sorry for my mistake :)

Is this Across the Dangerous Ocean...?

Because want to track down the strange disappearance of friends from two years ago, so Wo Ni quietly rushed into the Casino, want to reach the target - Heirloom Rochester-Madi. Unfortunately, she was forced to dance to Madi. It is only a wish to approach the truth. But, unintentionally, it falls into a deeper spin of the plot. Friendship, Love, is still a mystery, after all, who is behind this conspiracy?


It's a full colour Chinese manhua set in modern times.
The female lead, Yuer Le, is a private investigator with reddish-pink hair.
The male lead, Maddie, is a wealthy heir with long blue hair.
In the first chapter, both characters are playing poker at a casino and she climbs over the table and ends up in his lap.
In a scene set two years earlier, she rescues him while both are scuba diving in chapter 4.
This isn't tagged with any sci-fi or fantasy tags and I didn't notice any such elements within the first few chapters.

You can read this at Web Comics.

Downvoting this seems counterproductive. After all, without IDing the story, we can't confirm whether it's on-topic or not.

Wow! You found it. Thank you very much. I thought it has fantasy elements to it such as transmigration and powers but it seems there was none at all. Sorry for that but thank you so much! You just solved this mystery manhua I've been finding for years:))
